# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason:<MyMapViewController 0xa9446a0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]

Tags: iphone, ios, dictionary

terminating app due to uncaught exception `'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<MyMapViewController 0xa9446a0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key destinationAddress.'`

**First throw call stack:**

```
(0xa8d012 0x1b57e7e 0xb15fb1 0xd76711 0xcf7ec8 0xcf79b7 0xd22428 0x12c30cc 0x1b6b663 0xa8845a 0x12c1bcf 0x1186e37 0x1187418 0x1187648 0x1187882 0x1193235 0x13923d2 0x11904f3 0x1190777 0xaf2833f 0x11907b7 0x2d8d 0x1b6b705 0x10a9920 0x10a98b8 0x116a671 0x116abcf 0x1169d38 0x10d933f 0x10d9552 0x10b73aa 0x10a8cf8 0x29f5df9 0x29f5ad0 0xa02bf5 0xa02962 0xa33bb6 0xa32f44 0xa32e1b 0x29f47e3 0x29f4668 0x10a665c 0x233d 0x2265) libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

Comment: This happens most of the time when you have an outlet connected in the nib but no such outlet in your controller. I would check all the outlets and actions in the nib and remove all of them and reconnect again to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

Check your .xib for the outlet `destinationAddress` and make sure it is linked correctly